# IIS ignores last part of the URL when contains .js

Tags: iis

Navigating to **www.mytestsite.com/wwwroot/lib/chart.js/dist/Chart.js** i get 404 error response.
Of curse, the file exist in that directory.

Then i tried (just for debuging purpose) to move the file Chart.js to the directory **www.mytestsite.com/wwwroot/lib/** and then i navigate again to the same url (www.mytestsite.com/wwwroot/lib/chart.js/dist/Chart.js) and i get the file perfectly.

For some reason, the iis is cutting down the last part of the url **www.mytestsite.com/wwwroot/lib/chart.js<strike>/dist/Chart.js</strike>**

Comment: One part of the problem is that IIS does not distinguish between lowercase and uppercase letters. That is why the file opens when you put Chart.js in the lib directory.

Comment: Is there another file in the lib directory called chart.js (lowercase)? If not, then why is that part of the path to get to ../dist/.. ? If so, what is the file? Or is it a directory. Having something.js as part of the middle of a URL is unusual.

Comment: The point of the problem is that after the first ocurrence of chart.js in the url, the iis ignores the las part

Comment: There is not enough information here to diagnose your problem. I understand what you are saying about the URL being cut off. The question is why is chart.js in the path? Is there a directory named chart.js?

Comment: Exactly! There is a directory named chart.js
And that is because bower create that directory name for the chart.js library

Comment: Check permissions on the directory and its subdirectories. IIS is easily blocked if it does not have permission to read a file or directory. Make sure IIS_IUSRS has read permission to chart.js and to dist directories.

Comment: This is not a permission issue. I have the right ones. I can acces the directory if i change the name of it